# Avoid round app logo for Nougat Version?

Tags: android

The round app logo is using instead of the square logo. The square logo shows when i remove the `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` from manifest file. But in oreo, the app logo shows the default one when I removed the `roundIcon`. After searching on the internet I came to know in oreo it only shows the round icon you can do nothing about it.

How can I set the **square icon** when there is a possibility to set square instead of round in all version (Nougat, etc)?

Comment: you can try this tool https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ for generating the logo you want (choose luncher icon generator)

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time. Your answer doesn't relate to question, the question is not about how to generate icons.

Comment: first of all it's not an answer it's a comment, then my point of view is that similar tools are meant to handle such cases, I did use this tool myself in one of the applications in order to get rid of the rounded logos issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can change icon shape in settings.
Eg: In pixel phone press and hold the **home screen** -> **settings** -> there you can change the shape of the icon.

You have to make an **adaptive icon** to support square and other shapes. For more info look at the adaptive icons here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive